# Problem with the verification of integral

Tags: integration

We know that the integral $$\int\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}dx$$ is the set of functions: $$y = \frac{a^2}{2}\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right) + \frac{x}{2}\cdot \sqrt{a^2 - x^2} + C.$$

However, if we differentiate y we get $$y' = \frac{a^2 + a|a| - 2x^2}{2 \sqrt{a^2 - x^2}}.$$

My question is, why do we have to choose the sign of the number a? Shouldn't the differentiation give exactly the starting function $\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}?$ Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried simplifying your derivative result?

Comment: @sai-kartik By simplifying you mean the absoloute value?

Comment: It isn't necessarily, if $a \lt 0$, @Toni.  If $a \lt 0$, then $a|a| \lt 0$, and hence $a|a| \neq a^2$.

Comment: @sai-kartik I know how to procceed after than step. So to make my question more clear, is it that $a|a| = a^2 ?$ I thought it should have been $|a| |a| = a^2$. Thanks again.

Comment: I think @Peter Foreman 's answer should clarify your question.

Comment: And you might want to delete your initial direction to write $a|a| = a^2$, prior to clarifying it is only true provided $a>0$, as I noted this equality is NOT true when $a \lt 0$, @sai-kartik

Answer (score 2):

The antiderivative you wrote is actually only correct for $a\gt0$. In general we have
$$\int\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{a^2}2\arcsin{\left(\frac{x}{|a|}\right)}+\frac{x}2\sqrt{a^2-x^2}+C$$
by considering the substitution $x=|a|\sin{(\theta)}$ or otherwise.

Comment: Indeed, thanks for the answer.